Conformal coordinates - Isothermal coordinates
Given a smooth and closed surface $S$ parameterized by coordinates $u,v$ such that its metric can be written in the form $ ds^2 = \phi(u,v)^2(du^2 + dv^2)$ implies that the coordinates $u,v$ are isothermal coordinates, satisfying $\nabla_S^2 u = \nabla_S^2 v = 0$, where $\nabla_S^2$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator.
Now say we know two coordinates $u',v'$ on a surface $S$ and they satisfy $\nabla_S^2 u' = \nabla_S^2 v'$. Does it imply that we are able to express the metric of said surface in the simple form $ ds^2 = \phi(u',v')^2(du'^2 + dv'^2)$ too?
